# How do I use a jQuery $(document).ready and an ASP.NET UpdatePanel together?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm rocking this bit of Javascipt in the `<head>` section of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('dl.expander dd').expander
        (
            {   slicePoint: 50,    widow: 2,   expandEffect: 'show', userCollapseText: '[^]' }
        );
    });
</script>
```

This works great the first time the page is loaded; however, when I click an `<asp:button>` that is inside an `<asp:updatepanel>` the page is partially refreshed, but the `$(document).ready` is never called again.

This is important, because this Javascript in the `$(document).ready` section is collapsing and adding a "readmore" option to a list of pararaphs (or dl's with class="expander") on the page, most of which should be collapsed by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to add a handler to the AJAX client side endRequest event.  See the links below for more information.  This "event" is called when the ajax engine completes a request to the server, and is necessary for any javascript running on content that is inside the update panel.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    });

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // code that you want to run when the request is complete
    }
<script>
```

Comment: I've been searching for a solution this simple for a long time now. Simplest solution I've found by far.