# Async postback not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using this gauge in my contentplaceholder.

http://www.dariancabot.com/projects/jgauge_wip/

MyControl.ascx:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jgauge.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jgauge-0.3.0.a3.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQueryRotate.2.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/excanvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl" class="jgauge" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var isPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>;
        if(isPostBack == "true")
        {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            prm.add_endRequest(onEndRequest);
        }
        else{
                var <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl;

                <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl = new jGauge(); 
                <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.id = '<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl';
                <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.init(); 
 }
    });

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args){  
        var <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl;
        <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl = new jGauge(); 
        <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.id = '<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl';
        <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.init();
}
</script>
```

In MyPage.aspx: (Contains dynamically created table having several such controls. putting the generated table on placeholder)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="phMain" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myBtn" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
```

I have script manager on master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

But after async postback (hitting 'myBtn'), gauge disappears. Please Help. Trying to solve it since couple of days.

Comment: Did you try to debug the js code?

Comment: I noticed in firebug that only outer div that holds the gauge is present on the page. Inner contents of the gauge are not rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with by going:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()
        .add_endRequest(<%=this.ClientID%>_ctlEndRequestHandler); 
    var <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl; 

    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl = new jGauge();  
    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.id = '<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl'; 
    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.init();
});

function <%=this.ClientID%>_ctlEndRequestHandler(sender, args){
    var <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl; 
    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl = new jGauge();  
    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.id = '<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl'; 
    <%=this.ClientID%>_ctl.init(); 
}
```

The only real difference is that the postback checks are no longer taking place. Your underlying problem is that `$(document).ready` will not fire on partial postbacks, which means that `isPostBack` is never actually getting set to true. Because of this, `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);` was never executing, meaning that your `EndRequestHandler` never ran.

**Edit**

The other issue is that naming the method `EndRequestHandler` is guaranteed to cause problems if you have more than one of the control at the same time. To get around this, I appended `<%=this.ClientID%>_ctl` to the name of `EndRequestHandler` to ensure it was unique.

More info:

[How do I use a jQuery $(document).ready and an ASP.NET UpdatePanel together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750368/how-do-i-use-a-jquery-document-ready-and-an-asp-net-updatepanel-together?rq=1)

http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: Should I keep EndRequestHandler function as it is?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that should stay the same. Will edit my answer to update.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried that. But I noticed in firebug that only outer div that holds the gauge is present on the page. Inner contents of the gauge are not rendered.

Comment: What do you mean by inner contents?

Comment: Like it has canvas, needle, & so on. It is rendered as: <div id="MainContent_11_ctl" class="jgauge"></div> only.

Comment: Did you use View Source to check this out? I just tried the IE9 and FF dev tools and could see the various divs that got rendered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18449/discussion-between-mike44-and-nickw)

Comment: Not sure why, but the call to `add_endRequest` may need to be moved outside of `document.ready` in order to work, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/256253).